# Get the word from a text which is in single cuotes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to take the word which is in single cuote(or any other character):

From this `var theText="this is the 'text'";`
I need to take: `"text"` because is the word in single cuotes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var theText="this is the 'text'";

var reg = /'(.*)'/;

var res = reg.exec(theText); // res returns array => ["'text'", "text"]

console.log(res[1]); // returns text
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Df9kL/)

Answer (score 1):

you can do as like this:

```
var theText="this is the 'text'";

var data = theText.split("'");

console.log(data[1]);
```

it will return you an array on [0] index you will get 'this is the' and on [1] index you will get 'text' because we split it with ' ' commas..